# Finding the length of a stringvar

Tags: python, tkinter, variable-length

I am trying to make a function that will add text to a text box if the variable behind it is empty. I was attempting to do this using the .len() function, but I get an

```
AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'length'.
```

My code is as follows:

```
line1var = StringVar()

line1var.set("")

def tobeplaced(value):

    global line1var

    if line1var.length() == 0:

        txtReceipt.insert(END, value)

foo = Button(root, text="foo", command=lambda : tobeplaced("foo")).pack()
```

What do?

Comment: Doesn't `len(line1var)` work?

Comment: @ForceBru: No. `TypeError: object of type 'StringVar' has no len()`. But you can do `if len(line1var.get()) == 0:`, although I prefer `if not line1var.get():`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Tkinter `StringVar` doesn't have a `.len` or `.length` method. You can access the associated string with the `get` method, and get the length of that string with the standard Python built-in `len` function, eg

```
if len(line1var.get()) == 0:
```

but it's cleaner (and more efficient) to do

```
if not line1var.get():
```

since an empty string is false-ish.

Here's a small (Python 3) demo:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label_text = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(textvariable=label_text)
label.pack()

def update():
    text = label_text.get()
    if not text:
        text = 'base'
    else:
        text += '.'
    label_text.set(text)

b = tk.Button(root, text='update', command=update)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW, you should *not* do

```
foo = Button(root, text="foo", command=lambda : tobeplaced("foo")).pack()
```

The `.pack` method (and the related `.grid` and `.place` methods) returns `None`, so the above statement assigns `None` to `foo`. To assign the widget to `foo` you need to do the assignment and the packing in separate statements, eg

```
foo = Button(root, text="foo", command=lambda : tobeplaced("foo"))
foo.pack()
```